# Cyclic faithfully flat modules

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, modules

I am looking for an example of a cyclic faithfully flat $R$-module that is not projective. Could someone help me?

Comment: Interesting question, and I certainly don't immediately see any examples. Could you clarify whether you want an example with $R$ commutative, or would a non-commutative example do? Also, if it's possible to give some motivation for why you want to know this then that might get the question more attention.

Comment: By the way, an obvious comment, but of course $R$ must be non-noetherian, as otherwise every finitely generated flat $R$-module is projective.

Comment: This is trivially impossible for commutative rings (if $R/I$ is faithfully flat, tensor it with $0\to I\to R\to R/I\to 0$ to find that $I=0$).

Answer (score 5):

Over a [von Neumann regular ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring), every (left or right) module is flat.  Furthermore, a finitely generated projective module is necessarily finitely presented.

Using these two facts, I claim that it suffices to produce a von Neumann regular ring $R$ with a left ideal $I$ such that:

1. $I$ is not finitely generated, and
2. $R/I$ contains a submodule isomorphic to $R$.

Indeed, condition 1 (along with [Schanuel's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_lemma)) implies that $R/I$ is not finitely presented.  And the flat module $R/I$ will be faithfully flat thanks to condition 2 because the inclusion $R \hookrightarrow R/I$ remains injective after tensoring with an arbitrary right $R$-module $M$ (by flatness of $M$), so that $M \cong M \otimes_R R \hookrightarrow M \otimes_R (R/I)$ as abelian groups.

To produce an example of such $R$ and $I$ above, we can use one of the more famous pathological examples of a von Neumann regular ring: the ring $R = \operatorname{End}_k(V)$ of all linear endomorphisms of an infinite-dimensional $k$-vector $V$ space over your favorite field $k$.  It's well known that $R$ fails to have the property of [invariant basis number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_basis_number) because $R \cong R \oplus R$ as left $R$-modules.  Using this, we may inductively write left module decompositions $$R = R_0 \oplus S_1 = R_0 \oplus R_1 \oplus S_1 = R_0 \oplus R_1 \oplus R_2 \oplus S_2 = \cdots$$ where each $R_i$ and $S_i$ is isomorphic to $R$.

In this way we obtain an infinite direct sum $I = \bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty R_i \subseteq R$ that is clearly an infinitely generated left ideal. And because $R_0 \oplus I \subseteq R$, we obtain $R \cong R_0 \hookrightarrow R/I$ as left $R$-modules. Thus conditions 1 and 2 are satisfied.